# How to calculate the Bayes result

Tags: r, bayesian

I want to calculate posterior probabilities of my result, but I can't find appropriate function.

This is my code, I learned it from [here](https://learnbayes.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/bayes-rule-in-r/)

```
prior = c(D = .0001, not.D = 1 - .0001)
like.D = c(pos=.99, neg=.01)
like.not.D = c(pos=.01, neg=.99)
likelihood = rbind(D = like.D, not.D = like.not.D)
data="pos"
bayes(prior, likelihood, data)
```

But I can't find function of "bayes", so I want someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The link for the function (at the link you provide) seems to have died so you would need to contact the page author. In this case it is not difficult to calculate, as *posterior = likelihood * prior* . So just calculate by multiplying the tables. Seems the calculation that you want is the probability of D (disease?) given pos likelihood (test?)

```
> joint = likelihood * prior
> # marginalise to calculate posterior (need to normalise)
> cs = colSums(joint)
> joint[,"pos"] / cs["pos"]
          D       not.D 
0.009803922 0.990196078
```

As an alternative you could frame it as a Bayesian network (disease -> test) using the `gRain` package

```
> library(gRain)
> d = cptable(~disease, values = prior, levels=names(prior))
> tt = cptable(~test+disease, values=t(likelihood), levels=colnames(likelihood))
> net = grain(compileCPT(list(d, tt)))
> net2 = setEvi(net, evidence=list(test="pos"))
> querygrain(net2)
$disease
disease
          D       not.D 
0.009803922 0.990196078
```